# ReactJS, not getting output on console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ItemsNumber Component: Not getting the desired output of console.log(length) instead i am getting undefined but hello is showing on the console.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ItemsNumber extends Component {
    state = {
        movies: this.props
    }
    count = 0;
    ItemsCounting = () =>{
        const length = this.state.movies.length()
        console.log(length)
        console.log('hello')
    }

    render(props) {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.ItemsCounting()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ItemsNumber;
```

The FakeMovieAPI file: This is file has 10 items. This value of 10 must be displayed via console.log(length)

```
const Movies = [
  {
    id: 'm7pbc81a',
    title: 'Matrix',
    Year: 1999,
    genre: { id: '193x', name: 'Sci-fi' },
    ratings: 8.7,
    cost: 15
  },
....... 
]
export function getMovies() {
  return Movies;
}
```

The App component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getMovies } from './Files/FakeMovieAPI';
import ItemsNumbers from './Pagination/ItemsNumber';
import Table from './Pagination/Table';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    movies: getMovies()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2 className="d-inline bg-success"> Motion Pictures Stall </h2>
        <Table movies={this.state.movies} />
        <ItemsNumbers items={this.state.movies} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The Output on the console is:

Undefined

Hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not using `props` items on `ItemsNumber`. You need update declare state like this:

```
state = {
  movies: this.props.items
}
```

When you using: `movies: this.props`, `movies` will is an object with property `items` like this:

```
movies = {
  items: [...]
}
```

So `this.state.movies.length()` is `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you Viet, It worked. Now i am getting 10 as an output on console.

Viet if you have time please provide an explanation for this.

Comment: I updated the explanation. Hope it can help

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't returning anything from function that's why it's undefined. Return your value from function like below

```
ItemsCounting = () =>{
        const movieLength = this.state.movies.items.length;
        console.log(movieLength)
        console.log('hello')
       return movieLength;
    }
```

Better way to use this

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props?.movies.items?.length}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry mate, I am still getting the same output

Comment: @neel Try this this.props?.movies.items?.length ,,, it should work

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your movies state as props to ItemsNumber in App.js like this:

```
<ItemsNumbers items={this.state.movies} />
```

So this.props in ItemsNumber.js contains your movie array in a key named items.

It's a good idea to console.log(this.props) to see the shape of your data there.

Also length is a property on Array, not a method.